# Fixing paragraph spacing in posts

Tags: posts

When I edit a post that I would like extra spacing between each paragraph section, then it crams the heading for the next section against the bottom of the previous paragraph no matter how much space I add.

Tried the trick of adding a line then `&nbsp;` but this doesn't work. I still get this:

[image]

I'm sure this is probably a simple fix, but the help posts claiming to fix this that I've found on Google have been no help.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following code in your CSS. (Considering that you are using `h1`)

```
h1 {
 padding-top: 5px;
}
```

You can see / play with the same sample on https://codepen.io/ankyit/pen/NzRjrL

Comment: This fixes lines with headings after them, but doesn't fix lines where which should just have simple line breaks. Those lines are also smashed together.

Comment: @eComEvo can you share the page where the issue is so we can provide resolution for it too